# Expecting 'android:screenOrientation="unspecified"' or '"fullSensor"' for this activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgraded my Android Studio to 3.6.0. Now, I get the following error in my `Manifest.xml` file.

> Expecting 'android:screenOrientation="unspecified"' or '"fullSensor"'
>   for this activity so the user can use the application in any
>   orientation and provide a great experience on Chrome OS devices.

Should I convert it to "fullSensor"? 
How can I get rid of this problem?

Orientation of my activities is **portrait**. I want to keep using portrait orientation in my activities.

Comment: add this flag to the android manifest activity tag

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is a kind of warning to inform developers that for big screen devices it is not good to restrict the orientation.
However if your application only supports portrait mode then this warning can be disabled by doing the following.

**Mac:** Android Studio -> Preferences

**Windows:** File -> Settings

**Then:**

1. Search for "chrome"
2. Uncheck "Activity is locked to an orientation"
3. Apply and ok.

[Unchecking step screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulw0f.jpg)
[image: Unchecking step screen shot for disabling warning]

This will only remove the warning for the current system. So this change will not affect the other users working on the same project. They will still see the same warning. In a way, it is good to make this change for the local system as everyone gets to know about this warning. However, if we want to remove this warning at the project level then the following can be used:
Add `tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"` in the manifest tag of your Android Manifest file.
For e.g.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
```

So this is your personal preference, whether you want every developer to be aware of this warning or you want to add the `tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"` in the manifest and mute this warning for everyone. I prefer to enlight everyone :)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks @nitesh

Comment: This will only remove the warning for the current system. So this change will not affect the other users working on the same project. They will still see the same warning. In a way, it is good to make this change for the local system as everyone gets to know about this warning. However, if we want to remove this warning at the project level then the following can be used: 
Add tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" in the manifest tag of your Android Manifest file.
For e.g. <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"...

Answer (score 61):

Given your application only supports **`portrait`** mode, you can ignore these errors by adding `tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"` to all of your activities or just to the top level `<manifest>` tag which will apply to all activities.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: This should be the answer, as the accepted one only works for the local user.  Adding the ignore to the manifest allows other developers to ignore the change as well.

Answer (score 7):

Add this to the manifest tag:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use portrait orientation just so you don't have to use Bundle to store data, please learn how to use Bundle. It is a hacky way of not having to use Bundle, but believe me this doesn't solve all your problems. Sorry if i am wrong, but i thought that by setting screen orientation is a great workaround. It just brings more problems in long run

Comment: PS. this reminds me, check MVVM architecture and ViewModel which takes care of Lifecycle