# do not allow rotation of an android application

Tags: android, android-orientation

The problem should be easy to solve: I don't want to rotate my android application and its webView.

I tried adding to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:screenOrientation = "portrait"
```

but it does not work.

How can I solve it?

I tried everything I found on the net.

Comment: Use lowercase for **android** and set it on each `<activity>` tag

Comment: thanks for the answer, in the code it was already indicated "android"

Comment: And still does not work? This is what I'm actually doing to prevent screen orientation changes

Comment: I solved by following this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60396601/expecting-androidscreenorientation-unspecified-or-fullsensor-for-this-a